# make php variable from plain text get file

Tags: php

currently i am using the below code to get a file from a site which tells me the current server status of a game server. the file is in plain text format and out puts the following depending on server status:

ouput:

```
{ "state": "online", "numonline": "185" }
```

or

```
{ "state": "offline" }
```

or

```
{ "state": "error" }
```

file get code:

```
<?php 
   $value=file_get_contents('http:/example.com/server_state.aspx');
      echo $value;
?>
```

I would like to turn the 'state' and 'numonline' into their own variables so i could output them using a if, like:

```
<?php 
$content=file_get_contents('http://example.com/server_state.aspx');

$state  <--- what i dont know how to make
$online <--- what i dont know how to make

if ($state == online) {     
   echo "Server: $state , Online: $online"; 
}  else {
   echo "Server: Offline";
)       

?>
```

but i have no idea how to turn the 'state' and 'numonline' from the plain text into a variable of their own ($state and $online), how would i go about doing this?

Comment: It's not plain text format, it's json. Use json_decode() http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php on the string you get the contents of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function:

```
$value = '{ "state": "online", "numonline": "185" }';
$json = json_decode($value, true);
print_r($json);

if ($json['state'] == 'online') {     
   echo "Server: " . $json['state'] . " , Online: " . $json['numonline']; 
}  else {
   echo "Server: Offline";
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [state] => online
    [numonline] => 185
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your data is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse it into a usable form:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http:/example.com/server_state.aspx'));

if (!$data) {
    die("Something went wrong when reading or parsing the data");
}

switch ($data->state) {
    case 'online':
        // e.g. echo $data->numonline
    case 'offline':
        // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`I would like to turn the 'state' and 'numonline' into their own variables`:

Maybe you are looking for [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php),

Example:

```
$value = '{ "state": "online", "numonline": "185" }';
$json = json_decode($value, true);
extract($json);

//now $state is 'online' and $numonline is 185
```